# How can I know through similarity how specific string is included in the sentence?

Tags: python

**How can I know through similarity how specific string is included in the sentence??**

---

- for example..

ex)
sentence : The community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems.

specific string : algorism

- after run

similarity : 0.8248242 (algorism - algorithm)

---

Now, I'm using Python&jellyfish.
What I am planning is to check the mail subject in Outlook and classify it based on a specific string list.

HELP ME.................

Comment: What kind of similarity?

Comment: Yeah, where does the number `0.8248242` come from?

Comment: The number 0.8248242 is just sample value.

Comment: I want to know the similarity of the inclusion relationship between the sentence and specific the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ?

```
import string
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similarity(a, b): # EDIT WITH YOU OWN SIMILARITY OF NOT CORRECT
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

def max_similar(sentence, string_to_find):
    result = ["", 0]
    # Remove punctuation
    sentence = sentence.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    # split to list
    sentence = sentence.split()
    for word in sentence:
        coeff = similarity(word, string_to_find)
        if coeff > result[1]:
            result[0] = word
            result[1] = coeff
    return result

print(max_similar("The community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems.", "algorism"))
```

Result :

```
['algorithm', 0.8235294117647058]
```

Comment: I just used your code but, the result so different.

sentence : The community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems.
word : algorithm

result : ['algorithm', 0.18556701030927836]

Comment: What is your python version?
Update the similarity method with your own comparision method ;)